# how to install font IBM Plex Serif in alpine container

Tags: fonts, alpine-linux

I want to install `IBM Plex Serif` in the alpine container, and I have read the official wiki https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Fonts and did not found the command contains the IBM Plex Serif. is it possible to install the IBM Plex Serif in alpine linux? or should I install the font offline? I have treid to copy the font into the alpine folder `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/IBM_Plex_Serif`, and run this command:

```
fc-cache -fv
```

still could not work, the `fc-list` did not show the fonts.The command `fc-cache -fv` shows info like this:

```
/app # fc-cache -fv
Font directories:
    /root/.local/share/fonts
    /usr/local/share/fonts
    /usr/share/fonts
    /root/.fonts
    /usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono
    /usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif
    /usr/share/fonts/LM_Roman_10
    /usr/share/fonts/Main
    /usr/share/fonts/noto
    /usr/share/fonts/source-han-sans
    /usr/share/fonts/source-han-serif
    /usr/share/fonts/zh_CN-Adobe
/root/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 8 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/LM_Roman_10: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Main: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/noto: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-sans: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-serif: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/zh_CN-Adobe: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/root/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/LM_Roman_10: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/Main: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/noto: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-sans: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-serif: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/zh_CN-Adobe: skipping, looped directory detected
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.cache/fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

I am sure the folder `/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif` contains the fonts file:

```
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif # ls -alh
total 80K
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jul 26 13:34 .
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        4.0K Jul 26 13:34 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-ExtraLight.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-Light.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-LightItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-Medium.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-MediumItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-Regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-SemiBold.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-Thin.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         131 Jul 26 13:34 IBMPlexSerif-ThinItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        4.4K Jul 26 13:34 OFL.txt
```

why still show the warning `/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs`? what should I do to fixed this issue?